# Why does Xcode 14.2 on Intel Mac show "Preferences..." on M2 Mac "Settings..."

Tags: xcode, settings, ventura

I'm bringing up Xcode on a new M2 Mac and noticed this.

Both Macs have Xcode 14.2.

Yet, Xcode shows "Preferences..." on an older (2018) MacBook with macOS 12.6.3, but Xcode shows "Settings..." on a newer Mac (2023) with macOS 13.2.1.

This is not causing obvious problems, but I'm curious why.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions about *why* Apple does something are considered off topic as detailed in the [Help].

Comment: System Prefs was renamed in Ventura.

Comment: @Allan This is an answerable question and is nothing to do with why Apple did something  - the point is as in Allan's answer- the issue here is not Xcode but it is the version of macOS. Agreed the answer needs a bit more flesh. The question is worth it as it is unexpected for an applications menus to differ on different version os an OS.

Comment: The question is "why is there a difference?", rather than "Why did Apple decide to do this?".

Answer (score 1):

Preferences has been changed to Settings in Ventura.